# Neural network - different input layers

Tags: image-processing, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, image-recognition

I've just started working on image recognition project, and wanted to add neural network to it. Right now i can transform images into an list of important point locations. I want to pass that list to the ANN.
Now I've read several articles about ANNs and always I see that input layer is constant. The problem is that the count of points may vary depending op input picture. Is there a special type of ANN that correspond to this task? 
(Sorry if bad English :)

Comment: I'll try to explain the task i have: I have photos of objects I need to classify. I know that only using the locations of junctions on the photo(important points) i can separate objects to different classes. the problem is that different objects may have different number of those points. So the input array length may vary depending on object on the picture. Right now I'm thinking of to ways to solve the problem: get the array of positions myself and then pass it to ANN, or use CNN(finding more information  about those). May be there is other way?

Comment: @user3155701
I've meant to pass whole image to the CNN not the array of points :P Something like is shown here [image](http://torch.cogbits.com/doc/tutorials_supervised/convnet.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I might have misunderstood you*

## Neural networks in image recognition

The preferred way to use neural networks for image recognition is by feeding the pixel values from a image, and let the neural network itself decide which features in the images that are important. These features will be then be "stored" in the weights of the neural network. Thus you should only feed the pixel data from a image and let the network classify the input data.

**An example**

[image]

Comment: The problem is that image itself is too big (500x500px or more)so this aproach will be too slow. I think CNN may solve this task?

Comment: CNN are indeed a favored image recognition network structure. But these networks also require your input to be uniform in size/length. I've never implemented a CNN network myself, so I can't give you any tips there. What I can say is: the CNN structure is favored because it is faster to train/learn the features of the images. By precalculating the features, you would force yourself to perform a lot of processing either ways.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a finite number of possible image sizes (i.e. 500x500, 640x480 and 1200x1000 - 3 possibilities) then you can have autoencoders for each of these possible size classes to convert the image to the smallest of the sizes (i.e. 500x500). Autoencoder should be able to use local correlation to come up with more concise representation of the image. Note that CNN basically does the same, but it does not exactly address your problem of having variable input sizes. Even in CNN you will have to have a constant number of input nodes.

Once you have a smaller representation of the image you are free to use any method since all the image after passing through the encoder have the same dimension. Possible down side of this method is you need to have sufficient training samples for all size classes to train the encoders.

Or you can do just the opposite: take all smaller image sizes and replicate their pixels as needed in each axis and convert them to the biggest image dimension. For example, if the biggest dimension is 1000x1000 and you get a 500x500 image, just duplicate the rows and columns of it to get a 1000x1000 version. Then use a method that is invariant to this local correlation/redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

simply, you can input zero to the neurons that haven't data.

Note that, zero input don't change the weight of neurons so it not have any effect on learning.